# Removing specific values from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am working on problems related to dictionaries and lists.

This is my input data

```
{12: [33, 1231, (40, 41), (299, 304), (564, 569), (1139, 1143), (1226, 1228)], 
 17: [9, 1492, (30, 43), (1369, 1369)], 
 20: [9, 1492, (30, 45), (295, 310), (561, 573), (927, 929), (1133, 1148), (1222, 1236), (1354, 1356), (1368, 1369)], 
 26: [34, 1364],
 27: [300, 1360, (918, 922)],
 36: [34, 1364]}
```

My objective is to remove key-value pair which contains only integer data type inside the list of values. (In this input data, I want to remove data such as 26: [34, 1364] and 36: [34, 1364]).

So, my output would look like this

```
{12: [33, 1231, (40, 41), (299, 304), (564, 569), (1139, 1143), (1226, 1228)], 
 17: [9, 1492, (30, 43), (1369, 1369)], 
 20: [9, 1492, (30, 45), (295, 310), (561, 573), (927, 929), (1133, 1148), (1222, 1236), (1354, 1356), (1368, 1369)], 
 27: [300, 1360, (918, 922)]}
```

What is the most efficient method to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
data = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if not all(isinstance(x, int) for x in v)}
```

You could be more fanciful, using `map` and the dunder method:

```
data = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if not all(map(int.__instancecheck__, v))}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary comprehension with `not isinstance(..., int)`:

```
{k: v for k, v in dct.items() if any(not isinstance(i, int) for i in v)}
```

Output:

```
{12: [33, 1231, (40, 41), (299, 304), (564, 569), (1139, 1143), (1226, 1228)],
 17: [9, 1492, (30, 43), (1369, 1369)],
 20: [9, 1492, (30, 45), (295, 310), (561, 573), (927, 929), (1133, 1148), (1222, 1236), (1354, 1356), (1368, 1369)],
 27: [300, 1360, (918, 922)]}
```

Comment: Nice De-Morgan's-Law demonstration :)

Comment: @user2390182 Yeah :) Both of our answers work but in a different way

Comment: Virtually the same. Both will short-circuit on the first non-int value. The `sum` approach has no short-circuiting at all, so  I would rate it second-class ;)

Comment: @user2390182 Added that in my answer, it's because `any` returns `True` whenever it isn't integer type.

Comment: Hi!! Thank you for your solution.

Comment: @TaarunSrinivas Hope it works.

Comment: Yes it works :)